# Cloudfoundry NGINX Buildpack with Stormpath

Tags: nginx, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I've gone through and downloaded the CF static buildpack (NGINX buildpack), and I've been able to adapt the nginx.conf to work as a reverse proxy gateway for my application's microservices, however now that I want to enable the gateway with Stormpath Authentication, I'm unsure where to go next.

I've tried to familiarize myself with NGINX, however there is so little documentation on implementing it as a cloud foundry buildpack that I'm having trouble. I'm used to node.js where I would specify required plugins in the package.js... however I don't see how I'm going to install the stormpath, OpenResty, lua, etc. plugins...

Any advice on how this is done would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The static file build pack is intended to serve up static files, not work as a reverse proxy.  You're already fighting against the current here.  Maybe take a step back.  Why are using using the static file build pack as a reverse proxy?  You wouldn't normally need to do this on CF.  What use case does this solve for you?  If you can give more details, perhaps a better way to accomplish your task can be suggested.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMikusa,

I'm using the cf static buildpack because the NGINX buildpack was deprecated and replaced with the static file buildpack. I've not seen another cf NGINX buildpack out there (If you know of a cf nginx reverse proxy buildpack, do share! :D )

Using the static buildpack I've been able to edit the nginx.conf so that requests to my gateway are reverse proxy-ed just fine, however I'm not too sure how to enable stormpath middleware.

I would think cf buildpacks have some sort of launch file that I could append a "install lua, install lua-rocks, install open-resty". Truth?

Comment: A couple things.  First, you haven't explained why you need a reverse proxy to your app.  That's not generally something you'd need to do on CF.  Second, it's a "static file" build pack not "nginx" build pack.  It is meant to serve up static files, not handle everything that nginx can do.  Because what you're trying to do is different fro the standard use case, my suggestion would be to fire up an Ubuntu Linux VM or the `cloudfoundry/cflinuxfs2` docker image, build Nginx from source including any modules you need, then push that with your config as an application using the binary build pack.